# how can I read multiple text files in several folders?

Tags: python, directory

I have corpus in text files that are divided in several text files in several folders. What I am doing is to calculate the entropy of them, but have hard time concatenating them in one text file. what I did is like below.

```
filenames = ['BrownA1.txt', 'BrownB1.txt', 'BrownC1.txt'.....]
with open("C:/Python27/TRAINING.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

But this method takes so many time. I have almost hundreds of txt file to read.
such like this. C:/Python27/acq/000916~012897, C:/Python27/alum/0009945~012875, C:/Python27/barley/0010141~0011953~ as you can see, there are almost 30 folders like that format, and below them are at least 30 txt files.
Is there any efficient way to read them?

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.walk` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to recurse into a folder tree. Of course, it is helpful if you put all your text files (or the folders containing the text files) into an otherwise empty root folder. Apparently you use C:\Python27 which does not seem to be the optimal choice.

So if your text files are collected in (subfolders of) C:\path\to\root\folder you can do something like:

```
import os
with open('c:/path/to/output/file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:/path/to/root/folder"):
        for f in files:
            if os.path.splitext(f)[-1] == ".txt":
                with open(os.path.join(root, f), "r") as infile:
                    for line in infile:
                        outfile.write(line)
```